# Open CV SIFT creates segmentation fault - exits with code 139

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I'm running python 3.6.10 on a MacOS X. I used to be able to run openCV's SIFT without issue but now I am getting a segmentation fault. I've recreated the issue below with example data. Is anyone familiar with this error?

```
import cv2
from skimage import data

cv2.__version__
Out[8]: '3.4.2'

image = data.astronaut()
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(image, None)
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Comment: Did you update to Big Sur?  There are some problems with OpenCV + Big Sur at the moment.  It is currently stable on Catalina, but once you go to Big Sur, unexpected problems happen when using OpenCV.  FWIW, this code runs on Catalina just fine.

Comment: Yes, I updated to Big Sur two days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to upgrading to Big Sur where the previous built version of OpenCV was on your previous operating system.  There are some incompatibilities when you use the binaries for the previous OS and you try to use it with your current OS.  The solution is to uninstall and reinstall the package so that it is properly built on your system.  This will require that you upgrade to the latest version of OpenCV though, so you won't be able to use 3.4.2 anymore.

In your terminal, do `pip uninstall opencv-python` or `pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python` depending on what flavour you installed, then reinstall by `pip install opencv-python` or `pip install opencv-contrib-python`.

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng..Unfortunately I uninstalled and install but still had problems compiling. (btw i think i can install a particular version e.g. pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.16, to get that SIFT algorithm). I can not import opencv into python code without an error.
Based on the following, it is trying to compile for Mac OSX 10 still:
'pip install opencv-contrib-python
Collecting opencv-contrib-python
  Downloading opencv_contrib_python-4.5.1.48-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl (51.3 MB)'

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your error. OpenCV 4 has SIFT available outside of contrib since the patent expired. However if you install the contrib version it should still be available. When you use pip, does it not proceed past the download step?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, yes it downloaded but still gave me trouble when I tried to import it into python.
Following your advice, I have now just started a new conda environment and reinstalled my packages anew. Now everything is working. I imported an earlier version of open cv. This will run SIFT.

Comment: As I mentioned, you don't have to use an earlier version of OpenCV.  SIFT's patent has expired so you no longer need to worry about access troubles.  Glad you managed to fix it.